# On the possibility of "weitweglichkeit" existing as an autonomous word

Tags: semantics

I know that German is the language of all, theoretically at least, lexical possibilities.

If I want to express the notion of *farawayness*, is *weitweglichkeit* a good enough option for it, or is there any other way that I might put this abstract idea into words?

Comment: Regardless of whether it would be advisable to use this word, since the word that you have created is a noun you have to capitalise it.

Comment: -lichkeit is the suffix of properties; in case you mean a state, it should rather be "das Weitwegsein"

Comment: Trying too literal a translation is not always a good idea (here, it somewhat works, would most probably be understood, but sounds extremely awkward). *far away* is *fern*, *entfernt* or *abgelegen* in German. Try one of the related substantives to these words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean the state of being far away? I have to disappoint you but German already has a simple, poetic word for it: *die Ferne*. (The translation "distance" does not cover the poetic power of that word.)

> In der Ferne leuchteten die Lichter des Hafens.

*The lights of the harbour gleamed in "farawayness".*

> Dieses Vorhaben ist nun in weite Ferne gerückt.

*This project has been moved into far "farawayness".*

One could build compound words on the spot, of course:

> Eine Herzensferne trennte die beiden seitdem.

*A "heart-farawayness" parted the two from then on.*

And of course, there's also the opposite *die Nähe*, which is the state of being near. Also used in a poetic sense but for mundane purposes, too. (English *closeness* is a good translation for some cases.)

> Ihre Nähe machte in nervös.

*Her "nearness" made him nervous.*

> Fremdenzimmer in Bahnhofsnähe.

*Vacancies near the station.*

Comment: Learning is never disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker, I'd strongly advise against using "weg" in compounds.

There are two "weg"s in German:
The lowercase "weg" with a short e sound, meaning "away" and the uppercase "Weg" with a long e sound, meaning "way". 
In written compounds, you lose all ways to safely disambiguate them - potentially leading to the garden path phenomenon (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence).

In this case, if I see your word, my language instinct translates it to something like "longwayness" or "widewayness" (äöü's remark plays a role there too, "-lichkeit" makes it sound like a property of a place) .. which obviously isn't what you have in mind. Even when reading it again now, it takes some conscious effort to spell it with a short e in my mind.
(Edit: Could be because it looks similar to "Beweglichkeit", which has a long e)

If you want a longer word than "Ferne", maybe try "Weitentferntheit" (it's a little awkward too, to be honest, but at least everyone will know what it means right away).